# Is RightJs (right-rails) ready for rails3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rightjs

I'm wondering if [right-rails](http://github.com/MadRabbit/right-rails)([rightjs](http://rightjs.org/)) is ready for rails3?

I'didn't found any replacement for the default `public/javascripts/rails.js`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it has Rails3 UJS module already built in the rails.js.

The only problem is that the `script/generate right_rails` doesn't work on Rails3 yet. So you'll need to generate the scripts on a clean Rails2 project and copy the things to Rails3 manually

All the other things helpers and javascript should be just fine